# Finding marginal distribution under change of variable of pdf

Tags: probability, density-function, change-of-variable, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

Question:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, each with probability density function
$$f(x) = \lambda e^{−\lambda x} $$for $x > 0$. 
Let $U = X − Y$ and $V = X + Y$ . Find the joint probability
density function $$ f_{U,V} (u, v) $$ of $(U,V)$, describing carefully the region of the $(u, v)$-plane in which $$f_{U,V} (u, v)$$ is non-zero.

Find also the marginal probability density functions $$f_U(u)$$ and $$ f_V(v)$$ of U and V , and
the conditional probability density function $$f_{U|V} (u|v)$$.

I am having trouble finding the marginal distribution.

My work so far: 
Jacobian = 1/2
$$f_{U,V}(u,v) =\frac{\lambda^2}2 exp(-\lambda  v)$$
Now I thought then $U$ would go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ since it can take any of these values?
Then $$f_U(u) =\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^2}2 exp( {-\lambda v}) \, dv$$
 $$f_U(u) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^2}2 exp( {-\lambda v}) \, du$$

This is clearly wrong since the second integral doesn't make sense. I think it's to do with my limits and when $f(u,v)$ satisfies the expression I gave it and is zero otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

Edited typo.

Comment: Why do you integrate over $u$ to find $f_U$? Also check the joint density $f_{U,V}$.

Comment: Thanks, was an error, I've now edited. I checked the joint density and I seem to get the same?

Comment: "describing carefully the region of the (u,v)-plane in which fU,V(u,v) is non-zero." Sorry but where do you even start "describing carefully etc."?

Comment: I did state that that was where my confusion lay... if I had known how to describe it carefully, I wouldn't have asked. I've figured it out now, it just wasn't entirely obvious to me at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$. We also have that

\begin{align*}
X &= \frac{U+V}{2}, \\
Y &= \frac{V-U}{2}.
\end{align*}

Hence,

$$ f_{U,V}(u,v) = \frac{1}{2} f_{X,Y}\left(\frac{u+v}{2},\frac{v-u}{2}\right), $$

where the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation described above.

Given that $X,Y\in[0,\infty)$, what can we say about what possible values $U$ and $V$ can take? This will give you the regions where $f_{U,V}$ is zero, and should follow straightforwardly from the possible values for $X$ and $Y$, and the definitions $U=X-Y$ and $V=X+Y$.

I'll let you take the rest from here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it! I got the same joint pdf of U and V as I detailed in my working above- for  So does that mean U can take values minus infinty to infinity, and V can take values 0 to infinity. But this doesn't solve my problem that the marginal distribution for v, doesn't evaluate?